# Bubblesort in javascript can't run?

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

Please can you tell me what is wrong to this implementation of bubble sort algorithm in JavaScript?

```js
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped)
}


console.log(bubbleSort([4, 25, 1, 6, 2])); // [ 1, 2, 4, 6, 25 ]
console.log(bubbleSort([13, 1, 9, 38, 8, 3, 1])); // [ 1, 2, 4, 6, 25 ]
```

Comment: Why bubble sort or both arrays is returning same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will return `undefined`.You need to return `arr` from the function.

If you don't want to modify the original array then make a copy of original array using `slice()`. In the below case it doesnot matter because arrays are not stored in any variable.

```js
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  arr = arr.slice()
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped)
  
  return arr;
}


console.log(bubbleSort([4, 25, 1, 6, 2])); // [ 1, 2, 4, 6, 25 ]
console.log(bubbleSort([13, 1, 9, 38, 8, 3, 1])); // [ 1, 2, 4, 6, 25 ]
```